# Word like "underlined" but for wiggly/squiggly/wavy/snaked lines

Tags: phrase-requests

Consider the following picture:

[image: Screenshot of some programming code]

The text `stream->readBytes` is …?

In my native language, German, it would be called "unterschlängelt", literally "under-snaked". Does English have an equivalent word?

Comment: *Undersnaked* is great! If there's not already a suitable word in English, I propose you coin that one.

Comment: A wavy red line (a Microsoft term).

Comment: I agree with @TinfoilHat and will use *undersnaked* whenever I can in future.  Alas, I don't expect to use it very often.

Comment: I prefer the more Latinate: subcorrugated.